# PageView%0A Facebook Pixel Event

Tags: facebook, facebook-pixel

We are seeing a Facebook Pixel event with the name of `PageView%0A`. Is this `%0A` at the end just the newline character that is being included for some reason?

This event only appears maybe once or twice in a 30 day period, but I'm curious whether anyone else has experienced this and how they dealt with it.

Comment: Most likely, yeah ... Are you feeding the event _name_ to the fbq function dynamically anywhere, and if so, where does the value originate?

Comment: No, we're using the default script provided by Facebook where the event name is hard-coded. This script is in our header. Interestingly, PageView%0A only appears to ever be triggered by iPhone.